# change value get from a dictionary if the key is invalid

Tags: python-3.x

If a key does not exist in a dictionary and you try to get the value for it, python will just return None, is there a way to change it so that it return something else?

Comment: If there is nothing attached to it then what will be the result?

Answer (score 0):

Just [tell it to return something else](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
>>> {'foo': 'bar'}.get('baz', Ellipsis)
Ellipsis
```